# Add refrences to MongoDB schema within Symfony project

Tags: mongodb, symfony, bidirectional

I'm trying to create MongoDB database with some references within Symfony.
In my context I have 2 documents **Customer** and **Meeting**, *One* Customer can have *Many* Meeting so that what I did :

**Meeting.php**

```
<?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Meeting
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Customer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="timestamp")
     */
    protected $creationDate;
```

...

**Customer.php**

```
    <?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id()
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Meeting")
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $username;
```

...

and then when I run the command line:

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update

I got :

*No identifier/primary key specified for Document 'FrontOfficeBundle\Document\Meeting'. Every Document must have an identifier/primary key.*

I tried by using **@MongoDB\UniqueIndex()** but no way.
I think that **@MongoDB\Id** is supposed as an identifier !!!

***Versions***

- Symfony 3.2
- MongoDB 3.4.4

Any ideas ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, first I added a field called $meetings in the document **Customer** and an other $customer in the document meeting like this :

**Customer.php**

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="meeting", mappedBy="customer")
 */
protected $meetings;
```

**Meeting.php**

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="customer", inversedBy="meetings")
 */
protected $customer;
```

Then run the command line to generate setters and getters:

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents mybundleBundle

And when I run a fixtures (Creating one customer then its meeting), everything work fine, you'll notice that the relationship *1 to many* has been defined in your document (I'm using compass to display mongoDB) as a **One-to-Squillions** model (for more details about 1-to-N relationship : (https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) that's mean the son document (meeting) contains the reference of the parent as shown below :

**Customer**

[image]

**Meeting**

[image]

In MongoDB the @MongDB/Id is a primary key and the foreign key and never try to define references to this unique field.

Thanks for your attention.